# Square root of differentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Let $T=d/dx$ be the  differentiation operator on vector  space $V=C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, the  space of real (complex) valued smooth  maps on real line.

To what extent, all subvector  space  $W\subseteq V$ with the following properties are classified?

> W  is  $T$-invariant and the restriction of $T$ to  $W$ has an square  root: That is, there  is  an operator $S$  on $W$ with $S^{2}=T$

In particular, does $V$satisfy this property? If  the answer is no, what is  an example of  a non zero $W$ which is  maximal with the above property?

Comment: Certainly $V$ cannot satisfy this property, as we can find by considering polynomial subspaces. A notion you may find relevant here is [fractional calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus); note that $D^{1/2}$ has defined in this way need not take smooth maps to smooth maps.

Comment: One interesting subspace is the linear span of all functions of the form $e^{\alpha x}\sin(\beta x)$ and $e^{\alpha x}\cos(\beta x)$ for $\alpha,\beta \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$; on such a subspace a square root could certainly be defined.  I could believe that this space is maximal, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  Thank you very much for your information  about fractional  calculus. Regarding your  second  comment, wha is the square root in this case?

Comment: It's clear what it does to exponentials: $D^{1/2}e^{\alpha x}= \sqrt{\alpha}e^{\alpha x}$. Maybe we could find what it does to trigonometric functions with Euler's identity.